# Проблема с кодом PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Хочу сделать так, чтоб при нажатии `"Ruby"` в `QlistWidget` открывалось окно, на которое код будет ниже.

Вроде бы делаю правильно, но приложение не работает так как я не знаю как обратиться к объекту `main.py` при клике `qlistwidget`, т.к. `clicked` или `triggered` не работают.

main1.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui  
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from main import MainsWindow


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)                    
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.565, y1:0, x2:0.508475, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 103, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnPullOut = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)    
        self.btnPullOut.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 31, 23))
        self.btnPullOut.setStyleSheet("QPushButton#btnPullOut{\n"
"      background:white;\n"
"      border:0px;\n"
"      }")
        self.btnPullOut.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("33333.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btnPullOut.setIcon(icon)
        self.btnPullOut.setObjectName("btnPullOut")
        self.frame1 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 480))
        self.frame1.setStyleSheet("background:black;")
        self.frame1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame1.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame1.setObjectName("frame1")
        self.frame2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 0, 480))
        self.frame2.setStyleSheet("background:white;")
        self.frame2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame2.setObjectName("frame2")
        self.btnPullOut.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)   
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, False)      

        self.btnPullOut.setCheckable(True) 
        self.btnPullOut.click()
        self.btnPullOut.installEventFilter(self)

#        self.listWidget = ListWidget() 
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()                                # +++
        self.listWidget.insertItem(0, "Python")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(1, "Java")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(2, "C++")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(3, "C#")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(4, "Ruby")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(5, "Kotlin")

        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.openWindow)                    # +++

        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setFont (QFont ("Arial", 22)); 
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("QListWidget::item:hover {background: rgba(158, 158, 158, 40);}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {background: transparent;}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {color: black;}\n"
"")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame2)
        lay.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 20, 0, 0)

        self._animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame2, b'size', self)
        self._animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QSize(0, self.height()))
        self._animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QSize(121, self.height()))
        self._animation.setDuration(200)

    def eventFilter(self, watched, event):
        if self.btnPullOut is watched:
            if event.type() == 2 and self.btnPullOut.isChecked(): 
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
                self._animation.start()
            if event.type() == 2 and (not self.btnPullOut.isChecked()):
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
                self._animation.start()
        return super(MainWindow,self).eventFilter(watched, event)

    def openWindow(self, item):                                  # +++
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        row = self.listWidget.Item(4)
        self.exampleApp = MainsApp()   
        self.exampleApp.show() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = MainWindow()  
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

main.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'C:\Users\JEGOR\Desktop\main.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.0
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(515, 588)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 440, 521, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 490, 521, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(60)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ваши пункты:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Не хватает пунктов?"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "КЛИКАЙ"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №1 100 ПУНКТОВ"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №2 100 ПУНКТОВ"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №3 100 ПУНКТОВ"))

class MainsWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = MainWindow()  
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этот раз вы сделали не сколько опечаток:

```
# - super(MainWindow, self).__init__()         # - MainWindow
super(MainsWindow, self).__init__()            # + MainsWindow
```

---

```
# - self.exampleApp = MainsApp()               # - MainsApp() 
self.exampleApp = MainsWindow()                # + MainsWindow()
```

Но это не самое страшное. Вы пишите:

> Хочу сделать так, чтоб при нажатии "Ruby" в QlistWidget открывалось окно ...

- метод `openWindow` принимает на вход `item` - это `QListWidgetItem`
- строка `row = self.listWidget.Item(4)` не правильная.
- чтобы получить номер строки надо использовать `row = self.listWidget.row(item)`
- но так как номер строки у вас будет меняться при изменении списка, вам надо использовать текст, который вы прописали в список.
- окно должно открываться только если вы нажали на `Ruby`, для этого вам надо сделать проверку.
- исправьте опечатки и замените метод `openWindow`  на:

---

```
def openWindow(self, item):                                  
    self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    # - row = self.listWidget.Item(4)                            # Item(4)

    if item.text() == "Ruby":                                     # +++
    # - self.exampleApp = MainsApp()                              # - MainsApp() 
        self.exampleApp = MainsWindow()                           # + MainsWindow() 
        self.exampleApp.show()
```

---

**полный пример**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui  
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from main import MainsWindow
class Ui_MainWindow4(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(515, 588)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 440, 521, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 490, 521, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(60)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ваши пункты:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Не хватает пунктов?"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "КЛИКАЙ"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №1 100 ПУНКТОВ"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №2 100 ПУНКТОВ"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №3 100 ПУНКТОВ"))

class MainsWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow4):
    def __init__(self):
# -        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()         # - MainWindow
        super(MainsWindow, self).__init__()           # + MainsWindow

        self.setupUi(self)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)                    
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.565, y1:0, x2:0.508475, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 103, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnPullOut = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)    
        self.btnPullOut.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 31, 23))
        self.btnPullOut.setStyleSheet("QPushButton#btnPullOut{\n"
"      background:white;\n"
"      border:0px;\n"
"      }")
        self.btnPullOut.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("33333.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btnPullOut.setIcon(icon)
        self.btnPullOut.setObjectName("btnPullOut")
        self.frame1 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 480))
        self.frame1.setStyleSheet("background:black;")
        self.frame1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame1.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame1.setObjectName("frame1")
        self.frame2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 0, 480))
        self.frame2.setStyleSheet("background:white;")
        self.frame2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame2.setObjectName("frame2")
        self.btnPullOut.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)   
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, False)      

        self.btnPullOut.setCheckable(True) 
        self.btnPullOut.click()
        self.btnPullOut.installEventFilter(self)

#        self.listWidget = ListWidget() 
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()                                
        self.listWidget.insertItem(0, "Python")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(1, "Java")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(2, "C++")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(3, "C#")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(4, "Ruby")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(5, "Kotlin")

        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.openWindow)                   

        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setFont (QFont ("Arial", 22)); 
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("QListWidget::item:hover {background: rgba(158, 158, 158, 40);}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {background: transparent;}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {color: black;}\n"
"")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame2)
        lay.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 20, 0, 0)

        self._animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame2, b'size', self)
        self._animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QSize(0, self.height()))
        self._animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QSize(121, self.height()))
        self._animation.setDuration(200)

    def eventFilter(self, watched, event):
        if self.btnPullOut is watched:
            if event.type() == 2 and self.btnPullOut.isChecked(): 
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
                self._animation.start()
            if event.type() == 2 and (not self.btnPullOut.isChecked()):
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
                self._animation.start()
        return super(MainWindow,self).eventFilter(watched, event)

    def openWindow(self, item):                                  
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
# -       row = self.listWidget.Item(4)                               # Item(4)

        if item.text() == "Ruby":                                     # +++
# -            self.exampleApp = MainsApp()                           # - MainsApp() 
            self.exampleApp = MainsWindow()                           # + MainsWindow() 
            self.exampleApp.show() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = MainWindow()  
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: NameError: name 'item' is not defined

Comment: а, уже не надо, исправил

Comment: @imapw_ будьте внимательны, никогда не торопитесь :)

Comment: @ S. Nick спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Это были ошибки в именах вызываемых классов, методов.
Строки, в которых исправления отмечены так: `# исправил`
**main.py**  :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'C:\Users\JEGOR\Desktop\main.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.0
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(515, 588)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 440, 521, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 490, 521, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(60)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 221, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 150, 151, 41))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ваши пункты:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Не хватает пунктов?"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "КЛИКАЙ"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №1 100 ПУНКТОВ"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №2 100 ПУНКТОВ"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОПРОС №3 100 ПУНКТОВ"))

class MainsWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # исправил

        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = MainsWindow()  # исправил
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main1.py** :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from main import MainsWindow


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.565, y1:0, x2:0.508475, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 103, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.btnPullOut = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnPullOut.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 31, 23))
        self.btnPullOut.setStyleSheet("QPushButton#btnPullOut{\n"
"      background:white;\n"
"      border:0px;\n"
"      }")
        self.btnPullOut.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("33333.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btnPullOut.setIcon(icon)
        self.btnPullOut.setObjectName("btnPullOut")
        self.frame1 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 480))
        self.frame1.setStyleSheet("background:black;")
        self.frame1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame1.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame1.setObjectName("frame1")
        self.frame2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 0, 480))
        self.frame2.setStyleSheet("background:white;")
        self.frame2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame2.setObjectName("frame2")
        self.btnPullOut.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, False)

        self.btnPullOut.setCheckable(True)
        self.btnPullOut.click()
        self.btnPullOut.installEventFilter(self)

#        self.listWidget = ListWidget()
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()                                # +++
        self.listWidget.insertItem(0, "Python")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(1, "Java")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(2, "C++")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(3, "C#")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(4, "Ruby")
        self.listWidget.insertItem(5, "Kotlin")

        self.listWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.openWindow)                    # +++

        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setFont (QFont ("Arial", 22));
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("QListWidget::item:hover {background: rgba(158, 158, 158, 40);}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {background: transparent;}\n"
"QListWidget::item:selected {color: black;}\n"
"")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame2)
        lay.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 20, 0, 0)

        self._animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.frame2, b'size', self)
        self._animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QSize(0, self.height()))
        self._animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QSize(121, self.height()))
        self._animation.setDuration(200)

    def eventFilter(self, watched, event):
        if self.btnPullOut is watched:
            if event.type() == 2 and self.btnPullOut.isChecked():
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
                self._animation.start()
            if event.type() == 2 and (not self.btnPullOut.isChecked()):
                self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
                self._animation.start()
        return super(MainWindow,self).eventFilter(watched, event)

    def openWindow(self, item):                                  # +++
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        row = self.listWidget.item(4) # исправил
        self.exampleApp = MainsWindow() # исправил
        self.exampleApp.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = MainWindow()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```